# The more uncontroversial vs Uncontroversial as might seem?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

> Uncontroversial as these particular examples of Mill’s might seem, they divert attention from a profound ambiguity in Mill’s definition of harm that his reliance  on  the  term calculated  encapsulates.
>
> *The Moral Foundation of Politics - Ian Shapiro [pp. 62]*

What does - **Uncontroversial as these particular examples of Mill’s might seem** means?

Does it mean - The more uncontroversial these examples are, the more the divert attention.?
Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence can be paraphrased as

> These particular examples of Mill’s might seem uncontroversial, but they divert attention...